# iPad: Keeping a selected table view cell on screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

On the iPad I show a `UIPopover` when the user selects cells in a `UITableView`. The cell stays selected until the popover is dismissed.

When the user rotates the device from portrait to landscape orientation and the selected cell was on the lower part of the screen, it will disappear after the rotation and the popover ends up pointing at another (indifferent) cell.

How can I make sure that the selected cell in a `UITableView` stays on screen when rotating from portrait to landscape orientation?

**Update:** Combining Caleb's and kviksilver's codes, the following is a working solution:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    CGRect activeCellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath];
    if ((activeCellRect.origin.y + activeCellRect.size.height) >
        (self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height))
    {
        // If a row ends up off screen after a rotation, bring it back
        // on screen.
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                      animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Update 2, on repositioning the `UIPopover`:** After the scroll command it is necessary to send a `reloadData` message to the table view. Then the `rectForRowAtIndexPath:` method will correctly report the **new** position of the cell (otherwise it will not, as it is not updated properly after the scroll-command)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On orientation change try checking indexPathsForVisibleRows to see if your cell is visible and then using scrollToRowAtIndexPath if not..  something like:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    if (![[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but there is still a problem: `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` does not return the "reduced" size of the rows array after the rotation. Caleb's suggestion of using the `-rectForRowAtIndexPath:` method does work, though.

Answer (score 2):

You already know which row is selected, right? You also know when the device orientation changes, or at least you can know that, because there are UIViewController methods for that. You can get the rectangle for the selected row using UITableView's `-rectForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and it's easy to make sure that rectangle stays visible using UIScrollView's `-scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method, which UITableView inherits.

Comment: Following on to kviksilver's method, there's also a `-scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:` that sounds like it does most of what I described in one step.

Comment: i totaly forgot about scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition :-D

Comment: @kviksilver, I totally forgot about `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath...` until you mentioned it. Teamwork. ;-)